# MySQL - unique constraints design

Tags: mysql, database-design, constraint, unique-constraint

I am using MySQL and looking to solve a problem with relational data. I am not sure it is possible but wanted to ask the community.

Please consider the diagram:

[image]

I would like to add a unique constraint such that only one `User` can have only one `Role` per `Event` (Which is stored in the `UserEventRoles` table). Not sure how this can be solved? Perhaps with different design? Also the goal is not have a scenario where keys can be "out of sync", such as users role would point to an event where that role does not exist.

`EventRoles` table describes which `Roles` are valid at each `Event`.

I am sure this problem has come up before with other database designs and would like know what the best approach may be.

Also here is a link to sql fiddle to play around schema and some sample data.

[sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dfa99/1)

Comment: Do you mean that any user cannot have more than one role per event? (that's @Willem's assumption and answer)

Comment: Or that in any event there cannot be more than one users with same role? (this seems weird as you could not have more than one Attendees in an Event.)

Comment: @ypercube: A single user may only have a single role at any event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fairly simple to accomplish by making some changes to your primary keys.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8dcdd/1

I changed the primary key of the `UserEventRoles` table to be a composite key of `user_id` and `event_id`. This forces each `User` to only ever have at most one `Role` per `Event`.

I also modified the `EventRoles` table to use composite primary key. The surrogate key provided no value and made the resulting query more complex by forcing you to join into the `EventRoles` table if you wanted to preserve the foreign key constraint between that table and `UserEventRoles`.

With this change, you make sure you never define a role twice at an event, and you can directly join the columns in the `UserEventRoles` table to the descriptive tables that actually contain data you want.

Comment: Composite keys - FTW! This exactly what I was looking for. Solves the problem perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO having both `EventRoles` and `UserEventRoles` are too much.

I'd propose to

1. move `user_id` column to `EventRoles`
2. create a unique constraint on `(event_id, user_id)`
3. optionally make `user_id` nullable to be able to lay out roles for event without assigning them to particular persons
4. get rid of `UserEventRoles`

Now to get your list

```
SELECT e.name event_name, 
       e.date event_date,
       r.name role, 
       u.name user_name
  FROM eventroles er JOIN events e
    ON er.event_id = e.id JOIN roles r
    ON er.role_id = r.id LEFT JOIN users u
    ON er.user_id = u.id
```

Note that `INNER JOIN`s are used to join `eventroles` with ref tables `events` and `roles`. `LEFT JOIN` is only used to connect to `users` and **only** because I made `user_id` nullable.

Sample output:

```
| EVENT_NAME |                       EVENT_DATE |     ROLE | USER_NAME |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  Beer Fest |    August, 15 2013 00:00:00+0000 | Attendee |       Bob |
|  Beer Fest |    August, 15 2013 00:00:00+0000 | Security |    (null) | -- not assigned yet
|  Beer Fest |    August, 15 2013 00:00:00+0000 | Security |    (null) | -- not assigned yet
|  Beer Fest |    August, 15 2013 00:00:00+0000 | Security |       Joe |
|  RailsConf | September, 15 2013 00:00:00+0000 |    Staff |     Sally |
|  RailsConf | September, 15 2013 00:00:00+0000 | Security |       Joe |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/11673/1)** demo.
*You can try to uncomment the last two insert statements and see that a defined unique constraint will prevent them from being successfully completed*

Comment: But it allows to insert `VALUES (1,4,1)` so `Joe` would be both `"Bartender"` and `"Security"` at the same `"Beer Fest"` event.

Comment: @ypercube Fair enough. Thanks for the input. It's fixed. Answer and sqlfiddle updated.